# How to get the average ping time?

Tags: networking, bash, awk

Here's a real result of my `ping 192.168.1.1` command:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=964 ttl=64 time=1018 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=965 ttl=64 time=921 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=966 ttl=64 time=847 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=967 ttl=64 time=866 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=968 ttl=64 time=895 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=969 ttl=64 time=858 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=970 ttl=64 time=886 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=971 ttl=64 time=890 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=972 ttl=64 time=888 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=973 ttl=64 time=910 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=974 ttl=64 time=915 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=975 ttl=64 time=937 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=976 ttl=64 time=933 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=977 ttl=64 time=947 ms
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=985 ttl=64 time=1.09 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=986 ttl=64 time=2.02 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=987 ttl=64 time=3.37 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=988 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=989 ttl=64 time=2.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=990 ttl=64 time=1.11 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=991 ttl=64 time=1.39 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=992 ttl=64 time=1.11 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=993 ttl=64 time=1.10 ms
```

For some unknown reasons, sometimes my WiFi connection gets very slow and the main cause is the ping time.

I should manually disconnect my WiFi and reconnect it.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I want to make it automatic. Here are the script snippets I came up with. But I can't put them together:

```
# Read time using awk
ping 192.168.1.1 | awk '{gsub("time=", ""); print $7}'

# Disconnecting from WiFi
nmcli con down WiFiName

# Reconnecting to WiFi
nmcli device wifi connect
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
while read Line; do
    echo "read line"
    echo $Line
done <<< $(ping 192.168.1.1)
```

Basically, I'm stuck at redirecting `ping` standard output to a while loop, and I'm stuck at aggregating the average time using the `awk` command.

How can I combine them together?

**Update**

For anyone interested in the final script, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe or `while`-loop are waiting for input, but your `ping` command never ends.

You  can use `-c` or `-w` flag:

```
-c <count>         stop after <count> replies
-w <deadline>      reply wait <deadline> in seconds
```

e.g.

```bsh
ping -c10 192.168.1.1  | awk '{gsub("time=", ""); print $7}'
```

---

But to get the average time, you can more easily parse the summary:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.475/0.475/0.475/0.000 ms
```

```bsh
ping -q -c10 192.168.1.1 | awk -F'[/=]' 'END{print $2, $6}'
avg 0.475
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. I can put that `-c10` inside a loop and constantly get the average. I'll test it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final script I came up with:

```
echo
echo 'What is the WiFi name?'
read WiFiName

if [ $WiFiName == '' ]; then
    echo "WiFi name can not be empty"
    exit;
fi

echo "Now checking ..."
echo

while true; do
    AverageTime=$(ping -q -c5 192.168.1.1 | awk -F'[/=]' 'END{print $6}')
    IsSlow=$(echo "scale=2; ($AverageTime > 5)" | bc)
    if [ $IsSlow == "1" ]; then
        echo "WiFi got slow. The average ping time is $AverageTime. Reconnecting ..."
        nmcli con down $WiFiName
        nmcli device wifi connect $WiFiName
        echo "Reconnected to WiFi."
    else
        echo "Average ping time $AverageTime"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @pLumo, thank you so much for your help. This works like a charm.